# Why is every new terminal window now opening in a Conda environment in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode.  Out of nowhere, every time I open a new terminal window, it launches it in a conda environment.  I haven't changed any settings (knowingly), so I'm not sure why it is now doing this.  Has anyone else come across this problem / know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the following command on on VSCode terminal

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

It won't have conda base environment activated next time you open VSCode terminal.

Note: It will only work if you have done `conda init` at the time of installation.

Hope, this answer will help you.

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Great! You are Welcome :)